# Disabling SeLinux

Tags: linux, redhat, selinux

I'm not sure if I remember when I installed red hat 5 on my server. So how I can be sure whether selinux is disabled or not?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simply try

```
grep -i selinux /var/log/dmesg
```

***Note:***
 The clean way to determine if selinux is enabled or not would be to use the `selinuxenabled` tool from `libselinux-utils` package. The  issue is that **your kernel could have selinux compiled and enforced, but** (for various uncommon reasons) **not have selinux-utils installed.**
This is a quite uncommon situation, but it resambles to yours :)

Comment: selinux_register_security:  Registering secondary module capability
audit(1253173647.322:2): selinux=0 auid=4294967295

what is that mean?

Comment: selinux=0 means it is disabled. Even if your kernel _has_ selinux support it is disabled.

Answer (score 4):

See [Administrator Control of SELinux](http://www.redhat.com/docs/manuals/enterprise/RHEL-4-Manual/selinux-guide/rhlcommon-section-0068.html) in the SELinux manual:

`selinuxenabled;; echo $?`

will display 0 if SELinux is enabled and -256 if it is disabled.

Comment: When i try /usr/bin/sestatus it says bash: /usr/bin/sestatus: No such file or directory , is that meaning selinux is not exists?

Comment: No, it only means the utility doesn't exist. Use the selinuxenabled tool instead, like Zanchey suggests.

Comment: It seems he has not selinux-utils installed, but his kernel supports selinux, being disabled.

Comment: I believe RHEL has a customized set of tools. They are installed by default.

Comment: What is default for you? On my systems I use --no-base in the ks @packages section, and my defaults on RHEL is to not have such tools

Comment: Actually the return code for selinuxenabled is 1 if disabled

Answer (score 3):

The standard interactive tool on RHEL is getenforce.  It outputs a message telling the user which mode SELinux is in: enforcing, permissive or disabled.

Answer (score 1):

In Red Hat systems, you could edit `/etc/selinux/config` and set:

```
SELINUX=disabled
```

Reboot and you are golden.

Comment: do I really need to reboot to disable it?